# NGINX: main location block overriding sub directory location?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, nginx-location

I've read a moderate amount of the documentation for location blocks, but I dont have much experience with RegEx so I am a bit lost on how to pull off what I am trying to do.  The following nginx config will probably explain what I want to do better than I can word it:

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php;


        location /blog/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @uwsgi;
        }

        location @uwsgi {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        }


}
```

`example.com/` is being served by a bottle app through uwsgi, and so all things under this location should be routed to the bottle app and handled there.  This is working fine as expected, however I am lost on how to add an 'exception' to the location rule so that `example.com/blog`, and everything under it `../sub1/sub2` etc. are not directed to the bottle app, but infact handled by wordpress and its PHP magic.

This seems like it should be very simple to set up, but it's proving very difficult to google simple solutions to these sort of problems, as everyone seems to bloat thier 'tutorial' configurations with tons of non-essentials that confuse a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may need some tweaks, but you should probably use a nested location block:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php;

    location /blog/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @uwsgi;
    }

    location @uwsgi {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

Notice that the default URI is changed to `/blog/index.php` which is hopefully where all of your WordPress files are located.

Comment: This is good and helped fix my problem, although I discovered another problem was in a misconfigured wordpress installation.  I had moved my wordpress files to a subdirectory, but apparently I needed to re-install it as well.  It wouldn't have worked properly without this fix though.